# Random walk generated by i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v. grows lineary (by wlln)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

My book says that for the random walk $W_n$ generated by i.i.d. $X \sim \text{Ber}_{\pm1}(p), W_0=0$ the law of large numbers implies that $\frac{1}{n} W_n$ grows lineary with  slope $2p-1$.

It is not explained why, so I wondered. I know the law of large numbers, but doesn't it say that if you repeat an experiment independently a large number of times and average the result, what you obtain should be close to the expected value? I do not understand how that implies the linear growth here and would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random walk is a sum of i.i.d. random variables. In this case, you can write
$$
W_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n,
$$
where $(X_i)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. $Ber(p)$ random variables. Then the law of large numbers tells you that
$$
\lim_{n \to + \infty}\frac{W_n}{n} = E(X_1) = 2 p - 1.
$$
Informally, this is indeed saying that $W_n$ (not $W_n/n$) grows linearly with slope $2p-1$.

Comment: thank you but isn't the expected value of the bernoulli distribution $p$? Oh no... I get it! Thank you!

Comment: Yes if it takes value $0$ and $1$, but yours takes values $\pm 1$, so $E(X_i) = +1 \times p + (-1) \times (1-p) = 2 p -1$.